# how to delete many test cases in soap ui?

Tags: soapui

I have around 50 testcases in my **Soap UI** project, but only 40 test cases are valid and I wanted to remove all those remaining test cases, rather than disabling it. I tried deleting it but it could be deleted only one by one. Is there any work around for it?

Answer (score 1):

The entire soapUI project is stored as a XML file. Click on the project and you will see the file location on the left-below side of the screen. Its name should end with xxx-soapui-project.xml

Search "testCase" in the project XML file and delete the test cases and save it. Finally you need to  reopen the soapUI or refresh the project.